# Getting the date before with python

Tags: python, datetime

I want the yesterday's date, however i get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Code:

```
import datetime 
    today = datetime.date.today
    day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    yesterday = today - day
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the `()`. That way you are not creating a reference to the method and getting a "builtin_function_or_method" but rather, calling it and getting a `datetime` object:

```
import datetime 
today = datetime.date.today()
day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = today - day
```